# Resolving Overload resolution ambiguity

Tags: kotlin

I don't understand why the following two `into` functions, would cause an  `Overload resolution ambiguity:`

```
public fun <Fiz> Boo.into(block: FizMorphBuilder.() -> Unit): FizMorphBuilder defined in com.ltrojanowski.morph
public fun <Foo> Boo.into(block: FooMorphBuilder.() -> Unit): FooMorphBuilder defined in com.ltrojanowski.morph
```

Why doesn't kotlin know given the type parameter which one to choose when I explicitly specify the type `boo.into<Foo>{}.morph()`?

```
class FooMorphBuilder(
    var a: String?,
    var b: Double?,
    var c: Int?,
    var d: Float?,
    var e: List<String>?
) : MorphBuilder<Foo> {
    override fun morph(): Foo = Foo(a = a!!, b = b!!, c = c!!, d = d!!, e = e!!)
}

fun <Foo> Boo.into(block: FooMorphBuilder.() -> Unit): FooMorphBuilder = FooMorphBuilder(this.a,
        this.b, this.c, this.d, this.e).apply(block)
```

And

```
class FizMorphBuilder(
    var a: String?,
    var b: Double?,
    var c: Int?,
    var d: Float?,
    var e: List<String>?
) : MorphBuilder<Fiz> {
    override fun morph(): Fiz = Fiz(a = a!!, b = b!!, c = c!!, d = d!!, e = e!!)
}

fun <Fiz> Boo.into(block: FizMorphBuilder.() -> Unit): FizMorphBuilder = FizMorphBuilder(this.a,
        this.b, this.c, this.d, this.e).apply(block)
```

Can I resolve this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions from the JVM point of view have the same type after type erasure, it will be something like (in Java):

```java
public void into(Boo boo, Fucntion1 block);
```

A function return type is not taken into account for such resolution at the JVM level.

Use the `@JvmName("unique name")` annotation with different parameters for each of the methods to ask Kotlin compiler to generate unique names for the methods at the JVM level.

**UPD**: You do not need the generic parameters for these functions, namely `<Fiz>` and `<Foo>`. You do not use them in the declarations, and Kotlin compiler cannot infer the types too

**UPD2**:
The compiler will not be able to guess the type of the lambda that you call, so you may need to specify the type of it explicitly too, e.g.

```
val builder : FizMorphBuilder.() -> Unit = { /*the builder lambda */ }
val z = Boo().into(builder)
```

We use the declaration with an explicit type to explain what exact builder lambda signature we need at that point.

Comment: Hmm... I think I do something wrong, but when I add `JvmName(name = "intoFooFromBoo")` and `JvmName(name = "intoFizFromBoo")` I still get the same error. Did I not understand you correctly?

Comment: You do not need the generic parameters, e.g. `<Fiz>` or `<Foo>`